# char * in a struct, pointing to a char array, then using strncpy. Trying to avoid dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c, pointers, struct, buffer, dynamic-allocation

```
struct person
{
    char age [3];
    char * name;
};

char nameBuf[20];

person Natasha;
person * p_person;
p_person = &Natasha;

Natasha.name = nameBuf;

createPerson (person * resultingPerson, int p_age, const char * p_name)
{

    sprintf(resultingPerson->age, "%03d", p_age);

    strncpy(resultingPerson->name, p_name, strlen(p_name));
}


createPerson (p_person, 29, "Chelsea");
```

This code fails at the strncpy call. I can't use dynamically allocated memory. What is the best way to handle this? Why doesn't this work once the name* is pointing to nameBuf[20] a char array and then using strncpy?

Thank you

Comment: and why not allocated memory?  better yet, why not C++?  you can get then get built in support for a lot of dynamic type operations with automatic cleanup.

Comment: by the way, describe what you mean by "code fails".

Comment: `char age [3];` is too small for format `"%03d"` which needs 4+ `char`.  `strncpy(resultingPerson->name, p_name, strlen(p_name));` does _not_ insure that `resultingPerson->name` will have a terminating null character `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, age is only 3 and you are trying to write 4 bytes 3 digits and a null.  Also, normally your length parameter to strncpy is the size of the destination minus 1 so that you have room to add null (if the source string is shorter, strncpy will add the null).

```
#define NAMEBUFSIZ 20
char namebuf[NAMEBUFSIZ];
typedef struct person
{
    char age [3];
    char *name;
} person;

person Natasha;
person * p_person;
p_person = &Natasha;
p_person->name = namebuf;

createPerson (person * resultingPerson, int p_age, const char * p_name)
{
    char tmpbuf[5];

    snprintf(tmpbuf, sizeof(tmpbuf), "%03d", p_age);
    memcpy(resultingPerson->age, tmpbuf, sizeof(resultingPerson->age));
    resultingPerson->name[NAMEBUFSIZ-1] = '\0';
    strncpy(resultingPerson->name, p_name, NAMEBUFSIZ-1);
}
createPerson (p_person, 29, "Chelsea");
```

It's still not clean, though.  Can you guarantee the age will be reasonable, and that only short names (19 or fewer characters) are passed?

NOTE:  changed sprintf to snprintf as the comment below is correct, sprintf is quite unsafe as your code example demonstrates

Comment: Never ever use `strncpy`.  It does not do what you expect, its  actual semantics are unknown to 99% of C programmers and are useless to almost every real life use case. If you thonk I am being dogmatic about this, check out `man strncpy`.

Comment: Of course you shouldn't use `sprintf` either because you risk buffer overflow as your example shows. Use `snprintf` instead.

Comment: Also, if you must use `sprintf()` use `snprintf()` instead, your code is extreamely unsafe, and `memset()` is absolutely unnecessary, use `strcpy()` and check the length of the string yourself, so a `strlen()` `memcpy()` combination would be better..

Comment: @chqrlie - strncpy is safe to use if used according to the man page.  the goal was not to rewrite the ops code but to answer the ops question (i.e., what went wrong).  I agree, never use sprintf, but using it in the case of the answer shows why the question code fails.

Comment: @iharob - you are right, memset is completely unneeded, one could rely upon the buffer already being cleared, or (since I work with many different machines and compiler, I usually just write a protective null to the last byte)

Comment: @Les char [3] age is not actually a string. It's simply a char array. This code was written as an example of a real life case I'm dealing with with a protocol that uses strictly chars. The actual struct has several members that are char arrays of 2 bytes each, no room for a null char, with the final member being a pointer to a char of variable link. I'm not to use dynamically allocated memory to make space for the final data member that is a char *. Instead I created a buffer, pointed to that, then used memcpy to populate the space. This fails at some point. I don't know why.

Comment: The actual struct I'm dealing with looks more like this:                          typedef struct
{
    char foo;          
    char ID[2];    
    char csbar[2];
    char csFuzz[8];   
    char csBiz[3];  
    char *pcContents;       
} stIHI_PROTOCOL_MESSAGE;                                                                   It's the *pcContents field that I'm taking issue with. I stepped through this with a debugger and it fails when I use memcpy to pcContents.

Comment: @Natasha - if char [3] is not a string, then don't use string routines to fill it.  Most string routines try to append with NULL.  Use buffer copy routines like memcpy instead.  If age is an integer and you need a string, format it exactly as you want it into a temporary buffer (with room for NULL), then memcpy only the 3 characters.

Comment: @tatasha - you can declare a buffer on the stack or at program scope and then assign pcContents to that buffer, just like you did in your question.

Comment: @Les - yes. I realize this was my problem. This issue is now resolve. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@chqrlie - you helped my track down my problem. My problem was that I didn't want a string, only a char array. When I was using sprintf it was clobbering my char * name that I had originally pointed to nameBuf[] by writing the final null char, which I was not expecting. I put it through a debugger and watched the address to the buffer change. I didn't know why that was happening until I read your comment.

I ended up writing my own itoa, without a null char, then ended by using memcpy().

Thank you for your help!